# Linking ABAQUS 2020 to Fortran compiler (Intel OneAPI - Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

I have a problem with linking Abaqus 2020 with Fortran Compiler, I need this for launching UMAT subroutines.
I have followed one of the many tutorials available online for linking the two, and everything appears ok as I get results from the command abaqus
  `info=system`

But then, if I ask to the Abaqus Command tool to verify everything is fine, I get this message:

Abaqus/Standard with user subroutines

```
     ...ERROR

        Abaqus did not complete successfully.

        Please see std_user.log for details.

     Continuing...
```

And, by checking the file *std_user.log*, I find the following message:

*LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open file 'user32.lib'
Abaqus Error: Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.
This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.
These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines
used with a previous release of Abaqus may need to be adjusted.
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors*

What am I missing?
Thanks for any contribution

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. You will have to explain the actual steps you are doing before you get the message. The *"I have followed one of the many tutorials available online"* is completely non-specific.

Comment: user32.lib is a Windows SDK library. You may not have installed Visual Studio correctly - you need the Desktop C++ environment and the Windows SDK installed from VS.

Comment: @SteveLionel you were right! I downloaded and installed Windows SDK from Microsoft and now the Abaqus Command check on *user standard subroutines* is passed! Still I have a problem with running the subroutine, I think I will ask a new question. Thanks also to Vladimir F for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Originally posted as comment, turned out to be the answer:

user32.lib is a Windows SDK library. You may not have installed Visual Studio correctly - you need the Desktop C++ environment and the Windows SDK installed from VS.